# What does the argument[0] means in JavascriptExecutor?

Tags: javascript, selenium

So I just did the "How to handle hidden web elements using the JavaScript executor method".

But I am still confused about the method

```
public static void selectDateByJS(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String dateVal) {
  JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
  js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" + dateVal + "');", element);
}
```

What does the `argument[0]` represent? What does it mean?

Comment: it is the first argument in a method `myMethod('a', 0, true)` then `arguments[0]` would reference the value `a`

Comment: In your case it's the webelement you are passing into it

Comment: see js arguments: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: And the [documentation for `JavascriptExecutor.executeScript`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Answer (score 1):

`arguments[x]` is a way to reference the parameters passed to a function/method.

Since `arguments` is an object you can access the values via their key.

Using this can be helpful when there are no parameters yet parameters have been passed in, for example: infinite arguments.

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.log('all', arguments)
  console.log('first', arguments[0])
  console.log('second', arguments[1])
  console.log('third', arguments[2])
}

myFunction('a', 0, true)
```